# Validate user permission with Firestore security rules for multi tenant app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have been working creating a multi tenant app in Firebase and Firestore. The current structure is somehow like this:

```
/users
/companies
/company_user (this links the company and the user, with userId and companyId)
/service1
/service2
```

Basically, each company might have some service enabled or not and users are assigned to companies. User can be linked to multiple companies.

I am creating some security firestore rules and I would like to be able to restrict read/write operations into each service documents depending if the user has a company linked or not.

Most basic rules are working however I would like to verify that each user has access to the company, and that the company has access to that service.

Basically this would mean checking in companies_user to see if the user has the company linked, then if the company has that service (each service document has a companyId field to verify)

I cannot see how this can be done using get() or exists().

Can this be done? Or should I restructure my data? Something like:

```
/companies/{company}
/companies/{company}/users
/companies/{company}/service1
/companies/{company}/service2
```

I am not a fan of this because this would mean having data all over the place, but maybe I am too used to SQL and NoSQL not so much.

Thanks

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen Is there a way you can comment on this? Thank you so much

Comment: Did you end up getting the rules sorted for this?  I am looking at a similar scenario myself.

Comment: @MadMac Yes, eventually I ended up having user/customers subcollections inside the companies collection and also a subcolleciton inside each user to make it easier to query the user linked companies. It takes more time and testing when you update because you have to make sure you update all the places but I use functions triggers to update every section. Then the rules are not that complex anymore. If you are very interested I can post an answer later with more explanation.

Comment: If you get the time an answer would be helpful.  There are not very many stackoverflow questions on this with good answers and there are multiple ways to do it so I think it would be useful to others also.

Comment: @sfratini please post your answer, I am very curious